# Please verify azure search service is up, restart the WebApp and try again

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to publish my new Knowledgebase from QnAMaker.ai to my Azure app service. All the set up is done in Azure, and actually I have already published 2 Knowledgebase without any issue. Now this message keeps poping up.

"Restart the WebApp and try again" doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through your question I see you have published 2  KBs sucessfully.  I would recommend you to check Search Tier. You are likely to encounter this issue if you are exceeding the limit.

The maximum number of knowledge bases is based on Azure Cognitive Search tier limits.

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/limits#knowledge-bases

If this is your case,you could consider for an [Upgrade the Azure Cognitive Search service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure#upgrade-the-azure-cognitive-search-service)